# Problem with the domain of two functions with one variable.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Good evening!

I would be really thankful if someone will help me.
I followed the usually rules: set the root $\geq 0$, denominator different from zero and the argument of logarithm strictly greater than zero. But my solutions are still different from the correct ones.
The functions are the following:

1. $f(x)= \dfrac{\sqrt{x-2}}{\log_2(x^2-4x+3)}$

The domain is $(3,2+ \sqrt{2}) \cup (2+ \sqrt{2}, +\infty)$.

2. $f(x)= \sqrt{2- \sqrt{\frac{x-9}{x-1}}}$

The domain is $(-\infty, -5/3) \cup (9,+\infty)$

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Comment: Also, please explain how you arrived at your answers.  It helps users of this site identify any errors you may have made.

Comment: For 1. I get the same answer as you. What is supposed to be the "correct" answer?. For 2. you've missed that the square roots can be $0$, but otherwise you are correct.